# How can I access a web application running on a VM on another host in the same VPN network?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn

I have a rather complicated situation here.
A Windows Server (WS) is running in the same VPN network as my Notebook (N). An Ubuntu VM (U) is running on WS using VirtualBox. The Web Application Wekan is installed on U and accessed via web browser using a specific IP Address and Port. I can already call Wekan from the Windows Server Web Browser by using the IP Address and Port of the Wekan application.
Now I want to call this Wekan using the web browser on my Notebook. How exactly do I achieve this? I already tried opening the Wekan Port in Ubuntu and the Windows Server Firewall. Both did not help.

Answer (score 0):

How have you configured the VM network card? Maybe it is configuret that only WS can access it directly? Do you want to pass the route to U still using WS IP address? Or connect to U via separate IP address?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Ideally I want to access Wekan using the IP Address Ubuntu is using.

Comment: ok, so check if you have NAT or bridget network set up in VM settings. You can read more about it here:
https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/
I personally use Bridget Network almost all the time